# how to fix django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "blog_no_of_views" does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

i am new to django , i was using sqlite for development and now when i switched to postgresql, i am getting below error

i have tried to see all the answers on stackoverflow and every other sites but it didn't help for me.

i have already tried to delete migration folder and run makemigrations and migrate it is still giving me the error on makemigrations itself.try to run 
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb it gives error on this command as well

```
(youngmindsenv) E:\young_minds\heroku\youngminds>python manage.py makemigrations

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends
\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "blog_no_of_views" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."views_count", "blog_no_of_views"."username" FROM "blog_no_o...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\young_minds\heroku\youngmindsenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
```

settings.py

```
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



SECRET_KEY = 'e-mc3z=m#6_w#lzy$eb%qik9fcdlqmzsfsdf9=5s(we74^)25q_ge5'


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['youngminds.herokuapp.com',"localhost"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'social_django',
    #'sslserver'
]

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
        'width':'auto'
    },
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'width':'auto'
    },
}

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',  # added for social login
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'young_minds.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'social_django.context_processors.backends',  # added for social login
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect', # added for social login
            ],
        },
    },
]


# for social login

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',  # for Google authentication
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',  # for Google authentication
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',  # for Google authentication
    'social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'young_minds.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

'''DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    }
}'''

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres@123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'





MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "gdfg@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'rtgdfg'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
import math
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

# Create your models here.
class Category(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

class about_page_details(models.Model):


    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    image = models.ImageField(default='default_content.jpg', upload_to='about_page')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000,default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "about_page_details"

class carousel_images_messages(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default_content.jpg', upload_to='carousel_images')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,default='Other')
    message =  models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format("images_800_534_resolution")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "carousel_images_messages"



class No_Of_Views(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    views_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} counts on "{}"'.format((self.views_count),(self.post_title).title())

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "No_Of_Views"

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE ,default='Other')
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=100,default="Please click to read more")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(default='default_content.jpg', upload_to='content_pic')
    image1 = models.ImageField(default='default_content.jpg', upload_to='content_pic')
    image2 = models.ImageField(default='default_content.jpg', upload_to='content_pic')
    image3 = models.ImageField(default='default_content.jpg', upload_to='content_pic')
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()



    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length = 200)
    date_commented = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    reply = models.ForeignKey('Comment', null=True, related_name='replies', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} commented on blog "{}"'.format((self.user.username).title(),(self.post.title).title())
```

i would be very grateful, if anyone can help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

### UPDATE

the problem is solved , i have done silly mistake of calling a function in urls.py which happens to be a culprit for this error , removing it solved the problem.

Thanks everyone for taking time out . appreciate your helps !

Comment: Looks like you did not migrate your database.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what steps should i follow?to get rid of this error

Comment: Try running: `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` before running the server again.

Comment: @Sam i am getting above error when i run python manage.py makemigrations.which you have suggested

Comment: The usual next step is to delete the contents of your migrations folders and then rerunning makemigrations/migrate. That error is usually caused by a difference in what's represented in your migrations folder, and your actual database. If this is just for development, and you don't mind losing data in your database, it might also be worth dropping your tables as well. But that's more involved and should only be done if necessary.

Comment: @Sam ya i dont mind loosing data. i have deleted the migration folder from both the applications that i have created , but still i am getting same error. cold you please help me further

Comment: I'm not too familiar with postgres, so I can't give you specifics unfortunately. Personally, I would temporarily switch the database back to a sqlite db to test whether that works. If it does, then the problem is definitely a conflict between your migrations and the postgres database. If it still doesn't work then it's something else.

Comment: @Sam switching to sqlite is working fine but with postgres there is a above problem, i cant move further due to this

Comment: You can always recreate the postgres database from scratch. As in, delete every table relating to that project and set it up again the same way you did when you first switched to postgres. It's definitely overkill, and doesn't really help you understand why the problem happened, but it will most likely fix it.

Comment: In future, the reason problems like yours happen is because Django tries to keep track of database tables (this is what migrations are). If Django says that a table exists, but it's not there in postgres you'll get this error. As you use Django, you'll figure out what you did that causes that error and learn to avoid it by using a better workflow.

Comment: even after deleting the migration folder of my django apps , why am i getting the same error on makemigrations command, i am so confused